# ShareKit skip share sheet iOS 8 for Instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c, sharekit

I am sharing an image from my app to instagram using ShareKit by doing this

```
UIImage *image = viewTheme.image;
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:image title:@"Check this out! "];
[SHK setRootViewController:self];
[SHKInstagram shareItem:item];
```

And it brings up a share sheet with a Facebook Button and a Open in Instagram button. So I was wondering if there was a way to call directly the open in instagram action or, if that's not possible, to remove that Facebook button ( and the More button too if it's possible).

[image] 
**UPDATE**

I have this in the app delegate

```
DefaultSHKConfigurator *configurator = [[MyShareConfigurator alloc] init];
    [SHKConfiguration sharedInstanceWithConfigurator:configurator];
```

And my configurator subclass is this one

```
- (NSString*)appName {
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary][@"CFBundleDisplayName"];

}

- (NSString*)appURL {
    return @"https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/";
}

# pragma mark - API Keys



- (NSString*)facebookAppId {
    return @"466611176835259";
}

- (NSString*)facebookLocalAppId {
    return @""; //Si no se usa se deja vacion
}

- (NSNumber*)forcePreIOS6FacebookPosting {
    return [NSNumber numberWithBool:false];
}


- (NSNumber*)forcePreIOS5TwitterAccess {
    return [NSNumber numberWithBool:false];
}

- (NSString*)twitterConsumerKey {
    return @"ZGcj7yhbGSDUlXHHlLBwkC1Dc";
}

- (NSString*)twitterSecret {
    return @"naFO0wcOvGtoGJS6jPNFRREKYhfLTiXa9UtD1mRezzFP0q3Xcv";
}

- (NSString*)twitterCallbackUrl {
    return @"http://www.twitter.com";
}

- (NSNumber*)twitterUseXAuth {
    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
}

- (NSString*)twitterUsername {
    return @"";
}


// Instagram crops images by default
- (NSNumber*)instagramLetterBoxImages {
    return [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
}

- (UIColor *)instagramLetterBoxColor
{
    return [UIColor whiteColor];
}

- (NSNumber *)instagramOnly {
    return [NSNumber YES];
}

#pragma mark - UI Configuration : Basic

- (NSNumber *)useAppleShareUI {
    return @YES;
}

- (UIColor*)barTintForView:(UIViewController*)vc {

    if ([NSStringFromClass([vc class]) isEqualToString:@"SHKTwitter"])
        return [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:151.0f/255 blue:222.0f/255 alpha:1];

    if ([NSStringFromClass([vc class]) isEqualToString:@"SHKFacebook"])
        return [UIColor colorWithRed:59.0f/255 green:89.0f/255 blue:152.0f/255 alpha:1];

    return nil;
}

- (NSNumber*)showActionSheetMoreButton {
    return [NSNumber numberWithBool:false];// Setting this to true will show More... button in SHKActionSheet, setting to false will leave the button out.
}
```

I created also a quick example of what I'm trying to do, you can download it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n09gnq4ul3lcdtk/sharePodTest.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

implement this method in your configurator subclass

```
///only show instagram in the application list (instead of Instagram plus any other public/jpeg-conforming apps) 
- (NSNumber *)instagramOnly {
    return [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
}
```

EDIT: I did some more investigation. ShareKit works as intended, and according to [Instagram dev guidelines](https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/). If you set instagramOnly to NO, you see much more options. So it seems that Facebook app is also capable to share @"com.instagram.exclusivegram" UTI, which is not very nice from them. But, unfortunately, there is nothing we can do with it, except filing a bug report at Facebook.

Comment: I already implemented that method. Same thing is happening when sharing to whatsapp

Comment: have you registered your configurator subclass with ShareKit?

Comment: Yes I did, I have updated the post with the code of the configurator

Comment: Also I updated with a quick example of what I'm doing, thanks!